# Something like HashMap but with convenience methods like putInt()

Tags: java

In the Java standard library, is there something similar to `HashMap` but with convenience getter / setter methods for primitive and common types, e.g. `getString()`? Something like `Bundle` in Android.

Comment: why you did not wont to write your own `getInt() and putInt()` methods?

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry I meant getter / setter methods for primitive and common types. I could write it myself of course but using something from the standard lib would be better.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve, for example, the Preferences API does what your asking, but is meant for the persistence of user values across sessions

Comment: @MadProgrammer short version: `initOrConnect(class, parameters)`. If an instance of `class` created with `parameters` is alreaady in the pool, it's not created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Pangea says, there isn't such a class in the Java SE class libraries, and AFAIK there isn't one in any of the mainstream extension libraries.

The `Preferences` API appears to be similar, but the API carries the "extra baggage" of a preference hierarchy and a preference persistence mechanism.  If you don't actually want to implement a preference mechanism, then this is probably the wrong approach.

Your best option would be to create a custom subtype of `HashMap<K, V>` or `HashMap<String, V>` and then add the convenience methods.  However, it strikes me that what you are doing here could be bad design ... in Java.  You are likely to have the fragility of dynamic typing (e.g. attempting to access "attributes" that don't exist) without the benefits.

Comment: Thanks, marked the answer as accepted. I don't think it will be bad design in my scenario, it's a tradeoff, I could do it in a more static way but that would have different disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any. You can write your own. However, I am not sure what is the true value here?

Answer (score 1):

Generics combined with autoboxing probably do the job:

If you declare your map as e.g. `Map<Integer,Integer>` then its put expects Integer arguments, and will box int arguments to Integer as needed. Similarly, its get takes an Integer argument, that can be a boxed int. It returns, in effect, an Integer that can be automatically unboxed to int.

Comment: I edited the question, I meant getter / setter methods for all primitive and common types. Something like Bundle in Android.